# Drupal update 8.9.11 to 8.9.15 generate a Unknown column error

Tags: drupal, upgrade

after update 8.9.11 to 8.9.15 drupal generating error i have update db also

error is ->

```
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: Exception in Day[day]: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_learning_target_id' in 'on clause': SELECT DISTINCT node_field_data.nid AS nid, COUNT(flagging_node_field_data.uid) AS flagging_node_field_data_uid, COUNT(node_field_data_paragraph__field_learning.nid) AS node_field_data_paragraph__field_learning_nid, MIN(node_field_data.nid) AS nid_1, MIN(node_field_data_paragraph__field_learning.nid) AS node_field_data_paragraph__field_learning_nid_1, MIN(flagging_node_field_data.id) AS flagging_node_field_data_id FROM {node_field_data} node_field_data INNER JOIN {node_field_data} node_field_data_paragraph__field_learning ON field_learning_target_id = node_field_data_paragraph__field_learning.nid LEFT JOIN {flagging} flagging_node_field_data ON node_field_data_paragraph__field_learning.nid = flagging_node_field_data.entity_id AND (flagging_node_field_data.flag_id = :views_join_condition_0 AND flagging_node_field_data.uid = :views_join_condition_1) WHERE ((node_field_data.nid = :node_field_data_nid)) AND ((node_field_data.status = :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND (node_field_data.type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_3))) GROUP BY node_field_data.nid; Array ( [:node_field_data_nid] => 547 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => day [:views_join_condition_0] => orientation_completed [:views_join_condition_1] => 1 ) in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql->execute() (line 1543 of core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/query/Sql.php).
```

Please help how to resolve that

Answer (score -1):

This table is from your field content called `learning`

You have to discover which content is from and why it dissapear.

Comment: Do you score negatively the answer without information?